# Who are the cloud computing "operators" and what do they do?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, cloud-computing

I want to refine my understanding of the term "operators" so I can use it properly myself. For example,

> Stackdriver aggregates metrics, logs, and events from infrastructure,
>   giving developers and operators a rich set of observable signals...
>   -- https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/

I probably do plenty of "operating" myself, but who are these operators and what are their duties?

Answer (score 2):

"Operators" in this case is simply referring to "users" of cloud services. This would likely refer to "system operators" (sysops) who are the ones administering the servers in the cloud (versus on premises).

To quote a different paragraph on the same page (emphasis added) "Whether you’re running on Google Cloud Platform, Amazon Web Services, on-premises infrastructure, or with hybrid clouds, Stackdriver combines metrics, logs, and metadata from all of **your** cloud accounts and projects into a single comprehensive view of **your** environment, so **you** can quickly understand service behavior and take action."

Operator is the person in charge of the system who uses the cloud platform. The person in charge of setting up and maintaining the systems/network/servers.